# Setting multiple rows in one table equal to multiple rows in another table based on multiple column values being equal

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a rather convoluted query.  Two tables are out of sync.  In one step of the processing, a 16 digit value is copied from one table to the other, and is getting truncated to just 10 digits.

I'm using a few pieces of information to copy the full 16 digit number over.  I'm trying to find anywhere where the 10 digit value matches the first 10 digits of the 16 digit value, and three other pieces of information in these two tables match.  Combined, they give almost 100% certainty that we have a unique entry.  This is the current iteration of my query:

```
UPDATE DB1.TABLE1
SET ID =
(
SELECT b.ID
FROM DB2.TABLE1 b
INNER DB1.TABLE1 a 
ON left(b.ID, 10) = a.ID
WHERE len(a.ID) = 10
AND a.STORE = b.STORE
AND a.DOCTYPE = b.DOCTYPE
AND a.DOCDATE = b.DOCDATE
)
```

The problem is, it's telling me the subquery is returning multiple results.  But I want multiple results.  I tried adding another `WHERE` statement after the parenthesis, and duplicating the last four lines of the subquery, but that's not working either.  I also tried using `WHERE EXISTS` and duplicating the entire `SELECT` statement, but that gives em the multiple results error as well.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is attempting to update every row in DB1.TABLE1 to what's returned by the subquery. Not only is that not what you want, but the statement fails because the subquery is returning multiple values.

What you need to do is correlate the two tables as part of the update statement, like this:

```
UPDATE DB1.TABLE1
SET ID = b.ID
FROM DB1.TABLE1 a
  INNER JOIN DB2.TABLE1 b
  ON left(b.ID, 10) = a.ID
    AND a.STORE = b.STORE
    AND a.DOCTYPE = b.DOCTYPE
    AND a.DOCDATE = b.DOCDATE
WHERE len(a.ID) = 10
```

Comment: That seems to be working, in that it doesn't give errors and is making changes, but I'm getting some confusing results all the same.  Initially, on my test databases, I've got 2 rows that are in the new correct state of matching 16 digit numbers, and 77 that are incorrect.  The query only claims to change 27 rows, but then there are 79 in the correct matching state.  I'm still researching this, but assuming it's reconciled, I'll check this off as the correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Due to some other problems, we had duplicate entries being added to DB2.TABLE1, which was causing the duplicate returns for select statements.  Do you happen to know if the UPDATE command changes values as it goes, which would then cause it to "ignore" what might have been a match initially?

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting question. I don't know for sure, but it seems plausible given that you're updating a column that's also used in your join criteria.